# Can't use the back-tick as keyboard shortcut

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using the back-tick ("`" left of the number 1 ) as my shortcut for the Guake drop down terminal.
I've set it for Guake from Guake's preferences.

Now, I've installed another terminal, Tilix. 
I want to make the back-tick the drop down shortcut for it.
I could not find find this option from Tilix preferenes.
So I went to "System Settings" -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts".

Turns out that trying to associate the back-tick character with any command, does not work and instead it's Disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it, indeed it doesn't let you.
The correct thing is to search the code of this module and lookup if there are any hardcoded restrictions on this key, if so i would ask why its restricted.

Anyway,
You have a workaround
I use this program in order to manipulate text and key shortcuts [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)
There you can map your key to execute whatever you want (using python script that you write inside the program itself)

For example `keyboard.send_keys("%s" %_date)`

I'm also sure there are other mapping keys programs that you can install in parallel

Comment: I've changed my mind. I'll stick with Guake. It can set it's own shortcuts and works pretty well for me. Thank you

Comment: sure thing, enjoy